Angular eslint rule violations never being reported A16
Our project was on Angular 13 and was already successfully using eslint after migrating to that from tslint.  Later we migrated from Angular 13 to Angular 16 and the message output from ng lint is now always "All files passed linting" even though there should be known violations (e.g. someVar == otherVar when the eqeqeq rule is in place).
We have run ng lint in debug mode and it's clear that the rules are being loaded successfully as well as the source code files being iterated over, but no violations are ever caught.
Ran
node_modules/.bin/eslint --debug [path/to/specific/file-name.ts]
The output of which confirmed that the rules are being loaded and file-name.ts is being processed.

Answering my own question for the benefit of anyone who might be similarly stumped.  The solution seems obvious in hindsight and if I'd gone into it with a better understanding of eslint config in general it wouldn't have taken as long.
Assumption: there are rules from both the @angular-eslint and @typescript-eslint frameworks you'd want to apply to your ts files
If the above is true, you need to turn off three specific rules for the *.ts files overrides section and set the non-template parser explicitly.  For *.html files do the opposite: use the template parser and turn the three rules on.   This is a more fine-grained answer than what's posted here Having Angular Migrate TSLint to ESLint Banana-In-Box Error and both that answer and the
See below for an approach that won't give the false-negative behavior described in my original question.  Namely if you blindly switch the parser to the template parser for typescript files (like I did), it'll just not process any rules for ts source code and report as a "clean" eslint session.  I'd argue that eslint npm package should auto-deactivate banana-in-box and the other two when it encounters *.ts files.
{
  ...
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],  // SOLUTION IS DIFFERENT FOR *.TS overrides vs *.HTML

       // CORRECTED HERE, BUT HERE'S WHERE MY PROBLEM WAS (used to be the template-parser)
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", 

      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "@angular-eslint"],
      "rules": {
         ...
         "@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box": "off",
         "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off",
         "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off",
         "eqeqeq": ["error", "always", {"null":"ignore"}],
         ...
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"], // SOLUTION IS DIFFERENT FOR *.HTML overrides vs *.TS
      "parser": "@angular-eslint/template-parser",
      "plugins": ["@angular-eslint/template"],
      "rules": {
          ...
         "@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box": "error",
         "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "error",
         "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "error",
          ...
      }
    }
  ]
}

